# Catching or avoiding tweepy AttributeError

Tags: python, error-handling, tweepy

Using `tweepy` to get tweets from the Twitter Streaming API, I have set up a listener according to tweepy docs. It runs perfectly, sometimes for days, but every now and then it stops with this error:

```
  File "my_tweepy_script.py", line 90, in <module>
    twitter_stream.filter(track=keywordlist, follow=userlist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 445, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 361, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 263, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 313, in _read_loop
    line = buf.read_line().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I guess that this means that there is a `string.strip()` somewhere in the Tweepy code, and that something has happened during streaming that causes there to be a `NoneType` object where there should be a string.

Is there any way to get past such disruptions, without the streaming script crashing?